# node degree distribution using R and igraph

Tags: r, sna

I would like to create a histogram of the node degree distribution of a social network. I have file called `socialNetwork.csv` with two columns representing edges between userA and userB.

Here is how I load the data into `igraph`:

```
library(igraph)
g = read.graph("c:\\Network.csv", format="ncol")
```

What is the best way to export only the degree value column of `degree(d)` to a csv file?

Comment: Do you mean you want to only export edges linked to nodes of at least degree `d`?

Comment: If you want to make a histogram why don't you just do: `hist(degree(g))` ?

Answer (score 2):

You sort of ask a few different questions in your original post, so perhaps clarifying which of them you would like answered and what you have tried would be helpful. That said, there are a few steps listed below that I believe cover most of what you mention.

If you have already loaded the graph into some object `g`, then to create a histogram of the degree distribution try:

```
hist(degree(g))
```

If you want to export this information to a .csv file, try:

```
df_deg <- as.data.frame(table(degree(g)))
colnames(df_deg) <- c('degree','count')
write.csv(df_deg, file = 'degree_dist.csv')
```

Or if you only want the "value" column which I interpret to mean the counts of vertices by degree, then try in place of the last line above:

```
write.csv(df_deg[,2], file = 'degree_dist.csv')
```